# How to use sed to replace 3 letter words?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to use sed to replace 3 letter words that end with og, with the word frog. I thought this would work:

```
sed 's/?og/frog/' filename
```

But it does not?

Comment: I see at least two errors, but when you ask a question like this you should give sample input, expected output, and actual output that highlights the problem.

Comment: "?" is a shell globbing character meaning any single character. The equivalent regexp metacharacter as used by sed, awk, grep, etc. is "."

Answer (score 2):

This could work for you.

```
sed 's/\<.og\>/frog/g' filename

.      matches one character 
\<     beginning of word anchor
\>     end of word anchor
```